# Flask Mongoengine Text Search Cannot resolve Field

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

Been pulling my hair out trying to get a text index created in MongoEngine.     All of my modules appear to be up to date and I do have text search enabled on my mongodb.  I can even create a text index on the collection if I use pymongo.  However, I would like to stay in MongoEngine.  I've tried several iterations of my model, but the following is a scaled back version that fails:

```
class Situs(db.Document):
    streetname = db.StringField()
    streetnum = db.StringField()
    dscrptn = db.StringField()
    meta = {'indexes':[{'fields': ['$streetname']}]}
```

Error at runtime is:
mongoengine.errors.LookUpError: Cannot resolve field "$streetname"

Any thoughts or suggestions would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are not initializing your mongo engine properly, so it cannot find the fields declaration.  Make sure all the imports are there, and you are setting up the flask app as well.  The important piece here is the **db** variable.  Try something like:

```
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "MYDARKLITTLESECRETRAINCOAT"
app.config["MONGODB_SETTINGS"] = {'DB': 'mongodb://mongodb.mydb/databasename'}
db = MongoEngine(app)

class Situs(db.Document):
    streetname = db.StringField()
    streetnum = db.StringField()
    dscrptn = db.StringField()
    meta = {'indexes':[{'fields': ['$streetname']}]}


situs = Situs()
print situs
```

Output should be:  Situs object

Let me know if that works or if you are getting some other kind of errors.

Comment: Ok, so why did this get down voted?  If you're going to down vote an answer, at least be specific as to why.  This works just fine for me, and I'm just trying to help over here, I even asked to let me know if it works or provide further errors.  sheesh.